# Accessing array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP array:

```
class MyItems {
  $items = array(
      'note' => array(),
      'abstract' => array()
  )
}
```

And I want to access `note` array with the follogin code:

```
$item = new MyItems();

$i = $item -> items;

echo $i['note'];
```

But I get `Notice: Undefined index: note`

Comment: var_dump($item); check what exactly coming in your $item object

Comment: You just posted invalid code. How can you expect it work? Why don't you post a proper question? Without any improves it's a candidate to close I'd say because it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Notice: Undefined index: notes
```

or

```
Notice: Undefined index: note
```

Comment: Spelling mistake. You are correct.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Juhana - or it should be written less cryptically. either way, he loses out on the +1 I might have given for the right answer.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks , I am new here.. Will make next tme

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class MyItems {
  public $items = array(
      'note' => array(),
      'abstract' => array()
  );
}
```

Add `public` before `$items` and a ';' after the last ')'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example,It's working

```
  <?php
  class MyItems 
  {
  var $items = array(
  'note' => array('test'),
  'abstract' => array()
  );
  }
  $item = new MyItems();

 $i= $item->items;
 $i['note']=10;
 echo $i['note'];
 ?>
```